# I use python parser with selenium and beautiful soup to sort through pages from the VK site. An incomprehensible error appears in a random place

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I use a python parser with selenium and beautiful soup to iterate through pages from one social network. The bottom line is that the program loads a lot of links to user pages and then analyzes each page in a cycle and outputs data (name, friends, subscriptions, etc.). At some point in the cycle, an error occurs, which does not load the next page. Moreover, it happens seemingly in a random place, i.e. I checked it on the same data.

**cycle code**:

```
people = BSFile.find_all(attrs={"class": "fans_fan_lnk"})

for i in range(len(people)):
    print(people[i]["href"])

x = int(input())

for j in range(len(people)):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    driver.get("https://vk.com"+str(people[j]['href']))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "AvatarRich__background")))
    main_page = driver.page_source
    time.sleep(0.1)
    BSFile = bs(main_page, "html.parser")
    MasForUnpack = []

    if BSFile.find(attrs = {"class": "ClosedProfileBlock-module__title--eb2WU vkuiTitle vkuiTitle--l-3 vkuiTitle--w-2"}) != None:
        print("Профиль закрыт")
        Numbers = BSFile.find_all(attrs={"class": "vkuiHeader__indicator vkuiCaption vkuiCaption--l-1"})
        TagOfName = BSFile.h2

        for st in TagOfName.stripped_strings:
            MasForUnpack.append(st)

        if (len(MasForUnpack) == 2):
            if (MasForUnpack[1].find('заходил') == -1) and (MasForUnpack[1].find('онлайн')== -1):
                print(MasForUnpack[0] + " " + MasForUnpack[1])
            else:
                print(MasForUnpack[0])

        if (len(MasForUnpack) == 3):
            print(MasForUnpack[0] + " " + MasForUnpack[1])

        #Names = BSFile.find_all(attrs={"class":"vkuiHeader__content-in"})
        for i in range(len(Numbers)):
            print("Друзья: "+ Numbers[i].string)
    else:
        print("Профиль открыт")
        Numbers = []
        Names = []
        Numbers = BSFile.find_all(attrs={"class": "vkuiHeader__indicator vkuiCaption vkuiCaption--l-1 vkuiCaption--w-1"})
        Names = BSFile.find_all(attrs={"class":"vkuiHeader__content-in"})

        TagOfName = BSFile.h2

        for st in TagOfName.stripped_strings:
            MasForUnpack.append(st)

        if (len(MasForUnpack) == 2):
            if (MasForUnpack[1].find('заходил') == -1) and (MasForUnpack[1].find('онлайн')== -1):
                print(MasForUnpack[0] + " " + MasForUnpack[1])
            else:
                print(MasForUnpack[0])

        if (len(MasForUnpack) == 3):
            print(MasForUnpack[0] + " " + MasForUnpack[1])

        for i in range(len(Numbers)):
            print(Names[i].string + ": "+ Numbers[i].string)
    print()
```

**Error message**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\_prog_files\Html\proba\2.py", line 51, in <module>
    driver.get("https://vk.com"+str(people[j]['href']))
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 441, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
```

I tried to change the chrome browser to edge, but I didn't do anything else, because I don't even understand what the problem is.

Also used this options for chrome

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options )
```

in the previous questions, I did not find an answer, because I do not work in linux and I do not understand all the points of the answers well.

Comment: Have you looked at the linked questions.  Did the answers there not work for you ?

Comment: @RohitGupta I tried this

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--shm-size=2g')
``` 

and changed the browser to edge. 
Nothing worked
In the answers to those questions, I did not find more information that I understand. I don't use dockers and linkus